# Angular 5 - To deploy in IIS

Tags: angular, iis

I am deploying an Angular app on an IIS server.

The web is displayed correctly, but when I refresh the browser it gives me a 404/500 (depends on base attribute setting and app.config) error.

In my index.html I have:

```
<base href = "/">
```

And my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
          <rewrite>
            <rules>
              <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
              </rule>
            </rules>
          </rewrite>
            <!--<defaultDocument>
            <files>
            <remove value="index.html" />
            <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
            </defaultDocument>-->  
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When in the browser I call the path, it looks correctly:

```
http://miweb.es/WebApp/index.html
```

In the angular router I have goes it to redirect me and it does well to this route:

```
http://miweb.es/WebApp/index.html/download
```

But, at this moment if I browser refresh it gives me the error 404/500 (depends on base attribute setting and app.config).

What am I doing wrong ?, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root routing file put `{ useHash: true }`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Yes, I did change it, but it did not work for me, but I will try again maybe I have got a mistake, thanks

Comment: Before I tried but I did not get it, now it has worked perfectly, thank you very much